# Rails mountable engine with isolate_namespace but without prefixed namespace on tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

Is there a way to configure the `isolate_namespace` method to not use prefixed table names?

```
class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  isolate_namespace MyEngine
end
```

> Additionally, an isolated engine will set its name according to namespace, so MyEngine::Engine.engine_name will be “my_engine”. It will also set MyEngine.table_name_prefix to “my_engine_”, changing the MyEngine::Article model to use the my_engine_articles table.[Isolated Engine Docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Isolated+Engine)

When designing a prototype I ran into an issue where I need the routes to use the isolated namespace pattern, but the database tables do not. This is because the mountable engine I am writing has it's own self contained database.

Don't want to dig much further if it's not possible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Rails 3 and 4**
Did a little digging into the Rails Engine codebase to find a solution.
If you define a method to specify the table name prefix (in `/lib/my_engine.rb`), it will just use that instead. So set returning nil works fine.

```
require "my_engine/engine"

module MyEngine
  # Don't have prefix method return anything.
  # This will keep Rails Engine from generating all table prefixes with the engines name
  def self.table_name_prefix
  end
end
```

Comment: Works! Make sure to keep the method outside the class definition and just in the module block like in the answer.

Comment: @keaplogik. Thanks very much. This saved me a lot of trouble. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: Yes, this works. Out of curiousity, how are you handle migrations of your engine, since you don't want them to be mixed with the main app?

Comment: In this case, I would think the parent app may not have any tables, or the engine knows what tables exist in the parent application. I shouldn't suggest you overwrite the prefix mechanism unless you know it won't impact parent applications. Basically, use at your own discretion.

Comment: I believe there is an extra `end` tag in this example.

Comment: @keaplogik's answer didn't work for me when using my engine's generators. Setting `table_name_prefix` had no effect. After digging into source code I decided to override `namespaced?` method defined in `Rails::Generators::Base` to return `false` inside my generator.

Comment: The answer was for Rails 3 and 4. If you are on Rails 5 it may no longer work.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in rails 5 ? Above solution dosent work in rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5, the solution seems to be declaring the following on whatever models you want within your engine:

`self.table_name = "name_you_want"`

This won't affect generation, but accomplishes the use case that the original poster asks about, I think.